# Langchain streaming output using a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, openai-api, langchain

I have managed to stream the output successfully to the console but i'm struggling to get it to display in a webpage.

This is the code to invoke RetrievalQA and get a response:

```
def get_openai_answer(query, chroma_folder, search_size):
    
    handler = StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()
    
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
        model = 'text-embedding-ada-002',
        openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
        )
            
    db = Chroma(
        persist_directory=f"./chroma_db/{chroma_folder}", 
        embedding_function=embeddings
        )
    
    retriever = db.as_retriever(
        search_type="similarity", 
        search_kwargs={"k":search_size}
        )
    
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
        model_name="gpt-4", 
        temperature=0,
        openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
        streaming=True, 
        callbacks=[handler]
        )

    # create a chain to answer questions 
    qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm, 
        chain_type="stuff", 
        retriever=retriever, 
        return_source_documents=True, 
        verbose=False
        )
    
    for chunk in qa({"query": query}):
        yield chunk


@app.route('/<int:link_id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def control_response_qa(link_id):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        print(query)
        if not query:
            flash('Enter Some Text')
        
        else:
            conn = get_db_connection()
            data = conn.execute(
                'SELECT * FROM summaries WHERE id = ?',
                (link_id,)).fetchone()
            conn.close()
            
            chroma_file = str(data['title'])+'_db'
            print(chroma_file)
            
            return Response(get_openai_answer(query, chroma_file, 4), mimetype='text/event-stream')

    else:
        return Response(None, mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

And this is the HTML extract:

```
      <form method="post" id="input-form">
         <input type="hidden" name="submit_value" value="qa_doc" />
         <textarea class="form-control" id="query" name="query" rows="4" value="{{ request.form['query'] }}" placeholder="Ask Questions On This Document"></textarea>
         <br />
         <button type="submit" id="link_id" name="link_id" value="{{ summary['id'] }}" class="btn btn-primary float-right" >Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br><br><br>
      
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="image-cropper">
               <nav>
                  <div id="result">
                  </div>
               </nav>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   var searchForm = document.getElementById('input-form');
   searchForm.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
   
     var formData = new FormData(searchForm);
     formData.append('query', searchForm.elements.query.value);
   
     try {
       const response = await fetch('/'+ new URLSearchParams({
   searchForm.elements.link_id.value}), 
         {
         method: 'POST',
         body: formData
       });
       const reader = response.body.getReader();
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
       while (true) {
         const {done, value} = await reader.read(); 
         if (done) break; 
         const text = new TextDecoder().decode(value); 
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += text; 
       }
     } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
     }
   });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The output is just a blank page with this

> queryresultsource_documents

The output streams correctly in the console, am I using the corrct callback handler? any help would be great

Comment: you need to redirect your page with response

Comment: thanks, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code

```
    @app.get("/")
    def helloworld(request: Request) -> Any:
       
        """Basic HTML response."""
        body = (
            "<html>"
            "<body style='padding: 10px;'>"
            "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
            "<div>"
            "</div>"
            "</body>"
            "</html>"
        )

        return HTMLResponse(content=body)
```